Why did the US Chamber of Commerce support the 1993 Clinton's healthcare reform?
Accoding to Wikipedia

In 1993, the Chamber [of Commerce] lost several members over its support for Clinton's healthcare reform efforts. The Chamber had chosen to support healthcare reform at that time due to the spiraling healthcare costs experienced by its members. However, House Republicans retaliated by urging boycotts of the organization. By the time health care reform became a major issue again in 2010–2012, the organization opposed such efforts.

First of all, I hardly know anything about the US politics. Just learning English, and I didn't understand the above passage.
I believe Clinton's 1993 healthcare reform was mainly about employers' bearing the healthcare costs of their employees. And it's natural the member businesses of the Chamber would oppose it. But why did "The Chamber had chosen to support healthcare reform at that time"? What about "the spiraling healthcare costs experienced by its members"? What spiraling healthcare costs the businesses were experiencing back then is the writer talking about? Whatever spiraling healthcare costs they were experiencing, wasn't accepting that Clinton's 1993 reform going to only make matters worse? Because it would additionally make employers bear employees' healthcare costs? Then why did the Chamber support it?


But why did "The Chamber had chosen to support healthcare reform at that time"? What about "the spiraling healthcare costs experienced by its members"? What spiraling healthcare costs the businesses were experiencing back then is the writer talking about?

The Chamber of Commerce is a business lobby, its members are businesses (corporations). In the US, one of the most common ways to get health insurance is through your employer. (Some) businesses include health insurance as part of (some of) their employees' compensation package and have to pay health insurers (and various middlemen) to deliver it. Dysfunction in the health insurance market (and broader health care system) means that providing this benefit costs employers more and more.

Whatever spiraling healthcare costs they were experiencing, wasn't accepting that Clinton's 1993 reform going to only make matters worse? Because it would additionally make employers bear employees' healthcare costs? Then why did the Chamber support it?

Employers already bear (some of) the employees' healthcare costs. Universal health insurance coverage does cost money and it has to be funded through taxes but it's not necessarily a bad deal for all employers. Whatever happens on the tax front and your opinion on the merits of various health care systems, the first-order effect for the employer would be to lower the direct costs of the benefits paid to employees.

Employers bear the vast majority of healthcare cost: typically greater than 75%.

@user71659 I didn't know the exact figure, thanks. That's not the only thing I had in mind though. In the current US system, employers pay a large percentage of the costs for employees who do have health insurance through their job. I don't know what the details of the Clinton plan were but if the system succeeds in covering more people, employers (collectively) could be asked to pay some percentage of insurance for a larger group of people. I guess that's the comparison an organization like the Chamber of Commerce would look at.
